# C++ 11 save memory by using pointer in class declaration

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory

most of the time I could find answers on stack overflow.

I am working on a project and I need some suggestions.

Class A will have millions of object/instance.
Class A have several members including Class B, C, and D, etc,.
Class B, C and D, etc. have many member Class H, I, J, and K, etc.

Class A will always only have one "effective" class member, which means only B or C  (or others) is used.
However, class B usually have more than one "effective" class members.

So what will be the differences in using "class B" or "class * B" in Class A declaration? Similarly, how about Class B declaration?

some illustration code:
Solution 1

```
Class A
{
  B b;//i assume once A has an object, both b and c will take memory
  C c;
}

Class B
{
  H h;
  I i;
}
```

or Solution 2

```
Class A
{
  B * b;  //only one of B or C may be used buy we don't know so far
  C * c;
}
Class B
{
  H * h;//a combination of h, i, j, k, etc may be used, we still don't know so far.
  I * i;
}
```

I am assuming by use empty pointer in class declaration (Solution 2), I can save a lot of memory during definition and program run. Because I know only one or a few of the pointers will be actually used.

What do you think?

Comment: Totally depends on your use case. I wouldn't recommend to use raw pointers though. Cjoose something appropriate from the standard c++ [Dynamic Memory Management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) library.

Comment: In your first solution Class A will have a copy of both B and C, so whenever you create an object of Class A it will call constructor for B and C. Pointers seems a better idea, but again you will only be using a single pointer at a time. Given you always have 'one' active only, you might want to look at discriminated union (or std::variant since c++11/14)

Comment: @user0042, Yes, since my project is based on C++ 11, I will use smart pointer to avoid memory issue.

Comment: @ChangLiao Good idea.

Comment: I recommend you don't see the smart pointers as just self-deleting pointers, but in terms of *ownership*. Using a shared pointer (for shared ownership) will save memory if you have lots of sharing of the data. Less so if you only have one or two shared pointers. As for pointers versus objects, remember that if you have a pointer you also need space *for the pointer variable*, in addition to the object that you allocate dynamically.

Comment: Furthermore, even using smart pointers you should remember that pointers can be hard to handle, and might lead to lots of undefined behavior situations if you forget null pointer checks.

Comment: @AlexG, that is what I thought. I will take a look at it. I was planning to use a simple flag indicator to control which one of them is actually active. Again, having nested class and millions of instance worries me even on a HPC.

Comment: Lastly, *why* do you need to "save memory"? Are you sure it's not a case of premature optimization? Usually all kind of optimizations (for performance or for resources) leads to code that is harder to read, understand and maintain. Doing it prematurely can make it much harder in the future when you need to expand or maintain the code. Concentrate on making good, maintainable code first and foremost. Then ***if*** there is problems with resources or performance, then you can measure and benchmark to find the hotspots and bottlenecks, and fix only them.

Comment: What @Some programmer dude said.

Comment: Not sure if you're still trying to solve this, but have you considered using [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for this case?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Judging from the fact that `A` may contain `B` or `C`, and having either does not change the interface of `A`, it seems `B` and `C` should inherit from a common base `BC` and `A` should have a pointer to that

```
struct BC
{
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};
struct B : BC
{
    virtual int foo() override { return 42; }
};
struct C : BC
{
    virtual int foo() override { return 420; }
};
struct A
{
    BC* bc;  // which should likely be...
    std::unique_ptr<BC> ubc;

    int foo() { return ubc->foo(); }
};
```

The same goes for `H` onwards, keep a collection of their common base pointers in `B`

If you find that the containing class has its interface changed significantly based on its contents, it is likely you are building a [monolith](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) that have a leaky abstraction. Consider restructuring.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. This reminds me of a better explanation of my project.
Take A as human, B C D are male, female and others.
H I J K ,etc are weight, height, age, etc.
I am trying to improve the readability and structure of a former project and so far this type of object/type-oriented approach is clearer for future development. But I am open to other approaches.

Comment: @ChangLiao Writing this makes me realize that you probably need more details concerning your use case. I have absolutely no idea if this fits your needs